# Date and Postgresql TimestampTZ not sproducing expected result

Tags: java, postgresql, date, datetime

I know that I have misunderstood something. But I cannot figure out what.

I have a postgresql server in UTC. In a table I have amounts charged each quarter.

```
amount_charged | create_date
   100         | 2017-11-24 22:00:00+00
   200         | 2017-11-24 22:15:00+00
   550         | 2017-11-24 22:30:00+00
             ...
```

Since this is in UTC and my timezone is Africa/Cairo if I wanted to sum all amounts for Nov 25 in Cairo, the expected result from above would be *850*

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM subscription_service.charge_quarter c 
WHERE date(c.create_date AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo' ) = 
date(current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo') ORDER BY c.create_date DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<ChargeQuarter> findAllByOrderByCreateDateDesc();
```

This indeed gives me *850*

Another query that I have is

```
@Query(value = "SELECT reason, sum(sum_amount) 
FROM subscription_service.charge_quarter c
WHERE c.create_date >= ?1 GROUP BY reason ORDER BY 2 DESC", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> findAllTodayRevenuesByReason(Date today);
```

And `today` is calculated by:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of('Africa/Cairo');
final Date today = Date.from(LocalDate.now(zoneId).atStartOfDay(zoneId).toInstant());
```

This also produces *850*.
However my understanding is that `Date` is the number of milliseconds from EPOCH. So what I am trying to do with `today` is to calculate the number of milliseconds that have passed from EPOCH when the clock in Cairo displays `2017-11-25 00:00'.

When I change the query above to:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT reason, sum(sum_amount) 
FROM subscription_service.charge_quarter c
WHERE (c.create_date AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo') >= ?1 GROUP BY reason ORDER BY 2 DESC", nativeQuery =  true)
List<Object[]> findAllTodayRevenuesByReason(Date today);
```

Then the number is getting bigger than *850* (say *1200*) because obviously it gets some numbers from Nov 24 as well. I would expect it do stay the **same**.

Apparently the `c.create_date AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo'` is *not* doing what I think is doing or `today` is not calculating what I expect it to calculate.

But at the same time if I do not cast in the first query to the timezone the query gives me less of *850* which means it does not take into account the time between `2017-11-24 22:00:00+00 to 2017-11-25 00:00:00+00`

So what does the `AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Cairo'` do in the first query and why this is not working for the second one?